# Static Atomic Global variable has different values between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have an issue where I have two threads in two different C++ classes, where one reads a, atomic bool and one changes it. I have defined it in a separate header file here which is included in both class files.

```
    static std::atomic<bool> readyToRead;
```

One class launches a thread which changes the value of readyToRead, and this function is passed to that thread:

```
void WhiteBoard::writePoint(int x, int y) {
    QMutex mutex1;
    bool binX[16];
    bool binY[16];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 15; i++){
        binX[i]=x%2;
        x/=2;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= 15; i++){
        binY[i]=y%2;
        y/=2;
    }

    if(readyToWrite){
        mutex1.lock();
        memcpy(GPIOX, binX, sizeof(binX));
        memcpy(GPIOY, binY, sizeof(binY));
        readyToRead = 1;
        mutex1.unlock();
    }

    qDebug() << "T: " << readyToRead;
}
```

The other class also has a thread which runs this function:

```
void DisplayBoard::readPoint() {
    valChanged = 0;
    QMutex mutex2;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    bool binX[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    bool binY[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    while(1){
        qDebug() << "R: " << readyToRead;

        if(readyToRead){
            mutex2.lock();
            memcpy(binX, GPIOX, sizeof(binX));
            memcpy(binX, GPIOY, sizeof(binY));
            qDebug() << GPIOX[0];;
            mutex2.unlock();
            valChanged = 1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= 15; i++){
            int b = 1;
            x = x + binX[i] * b;
            b *= 2;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j <= 15; j++){
            int b = 1;
            y = y + binY[j] * b;
            b *= 2;
        }

        point.setX(x);
        point.setY(y);


    }

}
```

What I want the code to do is to run the code in the if statement in the second thread, when the first thread changes the value of readyToRead. readyToWrite, GPIOX and GPIOY are all global variables, where readyToWrite is also atomic and set to 1 before the thread launches. However, even when I can see that the value of readyToRead has changed in the first thread to true, it remains false in the second.

Thank you in advance for any help,
I apologise for any mistakes in the question. I am very new to this platform and programming in general.

Comment: if `mutex1` and `mutex2` are different objects, then they dont help to synchronize the threads

Comment: Ok, can I ask, where should I define QMutex then?

Comment: Including a header with `static std::atomic<bool> readyToRead;` in two *different* source files will create two *different* variables (both of  'file-local' scope) - one in each file. Declare the variable as `extern std::atomic<bool> readyToRead;` in the header, and instatiate it in *one* source file, with `std::atomic<bool> readyToRead = true;` (or `false`, if you want that as the initial state).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this seems to produce an error message saying "copying of variable of type std::atomic<bool> invokes deleted constructor"

Comment: @AdrianMole has given you the correct answer so where in the posted code does this error occur?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, the error isn't there anymore when I added {} around the false. Thank You